How to display a select box from all possible tags in django-admin when using django-taggit?
I'm trying to display a field for tags in the Django admin panel for each post, in which you can enter the desired tag or select from all available tags. It is not possible to select from all available tags. Tell me how exactly this should be implemented?
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db import models
from taggit.forms import TagWidget
from .models import Post, Comment

@admin.register(Post)
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('title', 'slug', 'author', 'body', 'publish', 'status', 'tags')
    list_filter = ('status', 'created', 'publish', 'author')
    list_display = ('title', 'slug', 'author', 'publish', 'status', 'get_tags')
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}
    raw_id_fields = ('author',)
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.ManyToManyField: {'widget': TagWidget},
     }

    def get_tags(self, obj):
        return ", ".join(o for o in obj.tags.names())


I can display all tags, but i want choose them. After tap them should go to the chosen tag box.
Now i display all tags like this:
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db import models
from taggit.forms import TagWidget
from .models import Post, Comment
from taggit.models import Tag, TaggedItem


@admin.register(TaggedItem)
class TaggetItem(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['all']


@admin.register(Post)
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('title', 'slug', 'author', 'body', 'publish', 'status', 
             'tags', 'all_tags')
    list_filter = ('status', 'created', 'publish', 'author')
    list_display = ('title', 'slug', 'author', 'publish', 'status', 
             'get_tags')
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}
    raw_id_fields = ('author',)
    # filter_horizontal = ('tags',)
    formfield_overrides = {
              models.ManyToManyField: {'widget': TagWidget},
              }
    readonly_fields = ('all_tags',)

    def get_tags(self, obj):
        return ", ".join(o for o in obj.tags.names())

    def all_tags(self, obj):
        return ", ".join(tag.name for tag in Tag.objects.all())

    all_tags.short_description = 'All tags'

